# Replacement BB chainline check?

Tags: bottom-bracket, chainline

I want to replace a bottom bracket (to add a torque sensor for a recent ebike conversion). **Current BB spindle length is about*** **114mm, replacement is 127mm**. So, all else equal, we're talking about **bumping the front chainline out by about 6.5mm (1/4")** which is a lot from what I've read?

Currently the **front chainline is about**** **43mm**. The rear dropout spacing is 135mm with a 9-speed SRAM cassette which is 36.5mm and 4.25mm from the outermost sprocket to the inside of the dropout. So I think the **rear chainline is 135/2 -4.25 - 36.5/2 = 45mm.** (So *if* I've measured correctly my chainline can actually absorb a bit of the bump out in the front.)

Potential concerns:

- Front derailleur: none, since there is none.
- Chain hitting chainstay: I tried just nudging the chain more than 6mm out and didn't see any chainstay issues
- **Chain rubbing on rear sprockets: is this a thing to be concerned about?** Or maybe because of the sprockets get smaller as you go out and I am increasing the front chainline, there is no issue?
- **Any other concerns I am missing?**

One potential solution I have read about is spacers between the chain ring and the spider.

**What do you think? I basically just want to figure out quickly whether this is workable so I can order the replacement BB.**

* I can't get an exact measurement because I don't have the right crank extractor on hand. I estimated by measuring the length between the outer edges of the crank arms and subtracting the height of the crank bolt heads and washers.

** I'm finding it's hard to measure precisely! In part because the BB shell is asymmetric on this bike with slightly more length on the drive side

Comment: Mentioning the asymmetrical shell at the end is a curveball. There aren't many bikes like that and it will lead to some special considerations. What is the bike? What are the cranks? Are you sure the shell is asymmetrical and you're not just seeing that the drive side of the spindle is longer? (This used to be common). Are the cranks you have suitable for running the ring on the other side of the spider tabs? Is the BB in question actually a torque sensor and it only comes in one length? Do the cranks have a removable chainring? Are you happy being committed to the ring size you have?